# Validate a token signature for subsequent request in a restful web api

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, token, jwt

When the user is authenticated I put a signed token in the response authorization header.

Every furthere access on a ressource url is only allowed with a valid signed token.

When I create the token and valdiate it:

```
var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(tokenString, validationParameters);
```

then I get the principal (user who made the request) when the signed key is the same which got

used by creating the token.

That I can use the same signed key after authentication and during the ressource request to validate the token I have created this class:

```
public static class ApiConstants
{
    private static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider CryptoProvider = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider(new byte[33]);
    private static byte[] key = new byte[32];

    static ApiConstants()
    {
        CryptoProvider.GetBytes(key);
    }

    public static byte[] GetSignedKey()
    {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong that I put this code in a static class which is actually my full purpose as I want the filling up of the byte array with random numbers to happen only one time!?

Is there still something I can improve?

Answer (score 0):

You Can't make the signature token as static. because then it will become as global variable and shared by all request(thread). Also you will face concurrency issue with static field.

If you want to make it session specific. then you need to store in a session variable not in a static field.

Comment: The problem is that the time of creating the token and validating the token are not within ONE request so how can the validateToken use the same secret key used in creating the token if its not static? I am not using sessions/cookies on the server side as I follow REST principles in my http api.

Comment: Maybe I have to put the secret key generation in an interface and inject this via autoface with .SingleInstance which is a shared singleton ?!

Comment: If the generated token can be shared to all request then it is ok to make the class static. I mean to say it will be one time generated token for all user/request.

Comment: @HelloWorld what about using dictionary to store your tokens and then validation from there.